# Unable to Run Tests on Edge browser in Jenkins

Tags: automated-testing, testng, jenkins, maven

I am trying to run my Tests in the Jenkins using Microsoft Edge.

When I click on build now, I am getting the below error in the Console Output

```
------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
[12:17:28.142] - Listening on http://localhost:7605/ 

Microsoft Web Driver can't be used with the Built-In Administrator account or while User Account Control is turned off.
```

I tried adding Nodes and then run the build, but still the issue persists.

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDge does not has a headless browsing version, running automation scripts via Jenkins requires headless browser modes. It will work fine for chrome and firefox.

If you want to run scripts on Edge via Jenkins, you might want to use a third-party tool like Browserstack.